# IComparable<T> in C++/CLI when T is implementing class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c++-cli

**Update:** as said in the comments, the C++/CLI should have been `value struct`; the compiler error 'clearly' stated "must be a value type".

---

In C#, I can write

```
      public struct Id<T> : IComparable<Id<T>>
    {
        public int CompareTo(Id<T> other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

When I try to do the same in C++/CLI

```
generic<typename T>
public ref struct Id : System::IComparable<Id<T>>
{
public:
    virtual int CompareTo(Id<T> other)
    {
        throw gcnew System::NotImplementedException();
    }
};
```

I get a compiler error `error C3225: generic type argument for 'T' cannot be '...::Id<T>', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type`.

Is it [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/112542/c-cli-c3225-generic-type-argument-for-t-and-use-of-typename) compiler error which still isn't fixed?

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558620/c-cli-boxing-and-generic-lists

Comment: Don't forget that in C++/CLI, `ref struct` means the same as C# `class`. To get the equivalent of your C# code, you need `public value struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments; the C++/CLI equivalent of C#'s `struct` is `value struct`, not `ref struct`.

Answer (score 5):

In C++/CLI, you need to use handles on the managed, reference types.  This compiles:

```
generic<typename T>
public ref struct Id : System::IComparable<Id<T>^>
{
public:
    virtual int CompareTo(Id<T>^ other)
    {
        throw gcnew System::NotImplementedException();
    }
};
```

Comment: While your code is correct, your explanation is not -- not all managed types need to be decorated with handles, only `ref` managed types. I.e., if `ref struct Id` were instead `value struct Id`, then the OP's code would have been correct as-is.